# Unity+ Caching: how to keep an object instance that should be a singletone

Tags: multithreading, caching, thread-safety, unity-container

I need my UnityContainer to contain an instance of CacheManager that should be created once and re-used for all future instances of containers.

I am creating new UnityContainer instance each time when I need it ('CreateChildContainer' is not used).

I've created static member that contains my cache manager and registered it's instance.

Looking on this after half-year, I don't like static members...

Will it work if I will create a single instance of UnityContainer and register there the instance of CacheManager with 'ContainerControlledLifetimeManager' option?

Do you see any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I think using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager is the recommended way ....

Answer (score 1):

Keep an instance of the container around and use ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. Creating lots of containers is going to perform poorly.

Comment: But I would like to have some items (like a connection to DB) to be alive only during request and create a new connection for each new request (ASP.NET web site). Can this be done using single container  which will create new container with 'CreateChildContainer' which in turn will register for own purposes the connection to DB?

Comment: You could do that, or use a separate PerRequestLifetimeManager and a single container.